# sort text files rows based on 2nd column

Tags: java, sorting, text, row, columnsorting

I have a text file in JAVA like the following:

```
number1 name number2
12      mike 2
3       jack 99
1       mike 23
0       lily 19
```

In JAVA, I want to sort the rows alphabetically ascending based on the 2nd column values. There are duplicate values too. So like this:

```
number1 name number2
3       jack 99
0       lily 19 
12      mike 2
1       mike 23
```

Is there a quick way of doing this instead of searching?

I can do this using search elements but I am looking for a quick and clean solution using collections, arrays, etc.

Comment: Create a class representing a row  implement Comparable interface. Read text file into a List of rows and use lambda to sort.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I don't want to sort based on rows! I need 2nd column as reference

Comment: Is there an example of what you are suggesting anywhere? @ChristophDahlen some sample code

Comment: You still need the entire row, even if you use the 2nd column for sorting.

Comment: ```static void printSorted(String path) throws IOException {
        Files.lines(Paths.get(path))
            .map(line -> line.split("\\s+"))
            .skip(1)
            .sorted((a1, a2) ->a1[1].compareTo(a2[1]))
            .forEach(a ->System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a)));
    }
```might do it for you